Why is my voltmeter reading the supply voltage instead of load voltage?
I am very new to electronics and am a physics student working on an assignment.
I have a very simple circuit set up in my bedroom:

A power source of DC +0.7A and +5.0V with a single resistor of 100 Ohms positioned in the center of the circuit.
An analogue voltmeter placed in parallel to the resistor reads a perfect 5.0V when I would expect it to have an altered voltage due to the resistor?

Can someone please explain why I get otherwise!, apologies for the simple question!

The potential difference across the resistor is that of the power source. Please clarify what you mean. Include a diagram if possible.

I'm not able to upload a diagram sorry.

I might be mistaken; would I not expect a change in voltage due to the resistor but instead a change in amperage?

What do you mean by a +0.7A power source?

The power source im using is an small phone charger with the wires cut, on the adapter it says it's rated at 0.7A 5.0V DC

Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with a good answer below.

You are right to be concerned, but in this case the voltage across the resistor is 5.0 V
Commercial voltage supplies are engineered so that they can provide the rated voltage over a wide range of currents, in your case 0 - 0.7 A.  With a 100 $\Omega$ resistor, the current would be expected to be $I= V/R = 0.05$ A, well within the capability of the power supply.  So it provides whatever current is needed to have 5.0 V across the resistor.

Ah I see! Thank you, I'm awfully new to this

If your voltmeter appears to be reading exactly 5.0V while delivering current to the 100 ohm resistor, it means the internal impedance of the power supply, which is in series with the 100 Ohm resistor, is sufficiently lower than 100 Ohms such that the voltage drop across the internal resistance is negligible.
Note that your power supply is rated to deliver a maximum of 0.7A. while supplying a voltage of about 5.0V. The current to the 100 Ohm resistor is only 0.05A, or less than 10% of the rated current. So the output voltage should be relatively stable.
Hope this helps.
